# Global POI database in JSON format?

Tags: data, geojson, point-of-interest

Does anyone knows if there is a flat file database of points of interest in a json format somewhere available for download? If not how would one set off to create such a database? Are there any tools available for such a task?

Comment: There are some websites that offers these data in many formats. You can ask at the following link: [Geographical data sets](http://thewebminer.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

You have this project that uses OpenStreetMap - http://openpoimap.org/ https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenPoiMap.
With overpass api https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API you can extract that info